# Revit API 2015 Python: GetAllViewports() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, api, revit

```
    data = UnwrapElement(IN[0])
    outlist = []
    for i in data:
        vs = ViewSheet.GetAllViewports()
        outlist.append(vs)
    OUT = vs
```

This kind of problem:

```
Revit API 2015 Python: GetAllViewports() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

What arg do I need to place in GetAllViewports()?

Answer (score 1):

The error "... takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)" is often a hint that you are calling an unbound instance method: Instead, get hold of the `ViewSheet` you are interested in and call the `GetAllViewports` method from there, as opposed to using the method on the class name (`ViewSheet`).